# Weakly referenced object won't get garbage collected

Tags: java, reference, weak-references

My concern is about an instance of an object that was once strongly referenced, but after an explicit null assignment to its strong reference and after an explicit `System.gc()` call, the instance is still reachable via **the weak reference**. If I understand correctly, when a referred object has only weak references left, the referent is guaranteed to be cleared in the next *GC* session. What am I missing?

Reference code:

```
public class References {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Example strongReferenceWrappedInWeak = new Example(42);
        strongReferenceWrappedInWeak.printA();

        WeakReference<Example> exampleWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(strongReferenceWrappedInWeak);

        System.gc();

        Example retrievedExample = exampleWeakReference.get();
        retrievedExample.printA(); //this works, because a strong reference is present to the instance, hence it's not cleared

        strongReferenceWrappedInWeak = null; //eligible for garbage collection

        System.gc();

        Example retrievedExampleTwo = exampleWeakReference.get(); //should be null
        retrievedExampleTwo.printA(); //should throw NPE
    }
}

class Example {
    private int a;

    Example(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    void printA() {
        System.out.println(this.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Garbage collection is not a predictable process.  It may just mark the object in first sweep and then clear in the next.  So any behavior which depends on GC process would indeterminate.

Comment: I'll take that as an answer to this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Not to mention, there is no guarantee that `System.gc()` does anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strongReferenceWrappedInWeak = null` does not make the `Example` object instance eligible for garbage collection, because **`retrievedExample` still maintains a strong reference to it**.

To fix, add `retrievedExample = null;`

```
Example strongReferenceWrappedInWeak = new Example(42);
strongReferenceWrappedInWeak.printA();

WeakReference<Example> exampleWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(strongReferenceWrappedInWeak);

System.gc();

Example retrievedExample = exampleWeakReference.get();
retrievedExample.printA(); //this works, because a strong reference is present to the instance, hence it's not cleared

retrievedExample = null;
strongReferenceWrappedInWeak = null; //now eligible for garbage collection

System.gc();

Example retrievedExampleTwo = exampleWeakReference.get(); //will be null
retrievedExampleTwo.printA(); //will throw NPE
```

Alternatively, don't create a strong reference with a local variable, just call the method directly off the weak reference. That way you don't accidentally leave a strong reference behind, as you did. *(During the `printA()` call, the `this` reference is a strong reference, so object cannot be GC'd *during* the call)*

```
Example strongReferenceWrappedInWeak = new Example(42);
strongReferenceWrappedInWeak.printA();

WeakReference<Example> exampleWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(strongReferenceWrappedInWeak);

System.gc(); //does not collect object, since strong reference still exists

exampleWeakReference.get().printA(); //works

strongReferenceWrappedInWeak = null; //eligible for garbage collection
System.gc(); //collects object, since it is now weakly referenced only

exampleWeakReference.get().printA(); //throws NPE
```

*Output (from both)*

```
42
42
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:**)
```

<sup>*Tested on Java 13*</sup>

Comment: IIRC there's an example of this in Java Puzzlers. That one uses the exception in a `catch` block for the strangely changing behaviour.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline What "strangely" changing behaviour?

Comment: I overlooked the part where I create a local variable that is going to get implicitly a strong reference to the referent. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Garbage Collection works in mysterious ways.

There have been several implementations of garbage collectors in the Java ecosystem, with very different behaviors.

When garbage collection runs varies by the implementation of the garbage collector, and also may depend on the current condition of the JVM. One collector might run almost continuously, while another might wait until low on memory. (I’m greatly oversimplifying here, to make the point clear.)

Whether all garbage is collected, or just some of it, may also vary by collector implementation and by the state of the JVM.

The call to **[`System.gc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#gc()) is merely a suggestion**, not a command. A garbage collector is free to ignore it.

In Java, you should not be making any great effort at managing memory. The modern JVM implementations are far better at that than any single programmer is likely to be. Just be sure to release all references to your objects when done using them. Or use `WeakReference`/`SoftReference`. Then trust the JVM and garbage collector to do its job.

In extreme cases (very large memory, or extreme volumes of object churn) you might want to study the behaviors of various garbage collector implementations. And maybe consider alternatives such as *Zing* from Azul Systems or *GraalVM* from Oracle. But for most projects, the usual OpenJDK-based JVMs work quite well.

Comment: While everything you said is true (up-voted for that), it wasn't actually the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813011/5221149).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, Basil. I was aware of the fact that my JVM was definitely going to do the cleaning job much better than I could (not that it's important in this small example), the explicit System.gc() calls were merely (as you said) suggestions to the JVM to clear the garbage in place, so that I could see the results of this experiment. I guess those calls are to be omitted/superfluous nearly always in real world projects? Cheers!